# Redirecting to chrome:// page results in Corrupted Content Error

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have a Firefox extension which opens a new window, and in that window at some point the address should be redirected to a local addon page (`chrome://myextensions/blah/somepage.html`). I can open that page by addressing it directly from the Firefox address bar, but when I try to redirect there from the server which serves the pages in the new window I get a firefox Corrupted Content Error (doesn't happen in Google Chrome).

I understand that it has something to do with headers, but I can't pin point the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not allow redirects from http:/https: to chrome: resources.

Comment: That sucks. Is there a relatively simple way to emulate such behavior?

Comment: Not really. You could the add-on listen for some custom event that the site dispatches and change the location from your add-on.

Comment: Was trying to avoid that solution. Thanks.